# Synchronized block in Java without main Object

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I am wondering why does Java require an object in a `synchronized` block. i.e.:

```
synchronized(object) {
    // stuff
}
```

Why can't I use a simple block without specifying any object? For example:

```
synchronized {
    // stuff
}
```

Comment: Because there might be dozens of threads working on unrelated things, and if they all had to wait for each other, it would slow things down considerably, and needlessly.

Comment: Synchronisation requires a monitor, which is a lock that guarantees exclusive access to an object's state. A monitor can be specified either explicitly (a synchronized block) or implicitly (a synchronized method, where a lock is either `this` or a class instance).

Comment: And what would it synchronize on, one lock for all blocks? This isn't Python.

Comment: What would you expect the behavior of this statement to be? That this means "synchronized with every other `synchronized <no expression>` block"? Or "synchronized with every other synchronized block, whatever they synchronize on"?

Comment: you can add code inside synchronized method, is that your direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html):

**Intrinsic Locks and Synchronization**

> **Synchronization is built around an internal entity known as the *intrinsic lock* or *monitor lock*.** (The API specification often refers to this entity simply as a "monitor.") Intrinsic locks play a role in both aspects of synchronization: enforcing exclusive access to an object's state and establishing happens-before relationships that are essential to visibility.
>   **Every object has an intrinsic lock associated with it.** By convention, a thread that needs exclusive and consistent access to an object's fields has to acquire the object's intrinsic lock before accessing them, and then release the intrinsic lock when it's done with them.

**Synchronized Statements**

> Another way to create synchronized code is with synchronized statements. Unlike synchronized methods, **synchronized statements must specify the object that provides the intrinsic lock**.